# if a task call with delay() when will execute exactly?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery-task

I'm new in celery and i want use it but i don't know when i call a task with `delay()` when exactly will execute? and after adding a new task what i must to do to this task work correctly? i use a present project and i extending it, but old task work correctly and my task doesn't .
present app1/task.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('notification')


@shared_task
def send_message_to_users(users, client_type=None, **kwargs):
    .
    .
    #doing something here
    .
    .
    logger.info(
        'notification_log',
        exc_info=False,
        )
    )
```

and this is my code in app2/task.py:

```
@shared_task
def update_students_done_count(homework_id):
    homework_students = HomeworkStudent.objects.filter(homework_id=homework_id)
    students_done_count = 0
    for homework_student in homework_students:
        if homework_student.student_homework_status:
            students_done_count += 1
    homework = get_object_or_404(HomeWork, homework_id=homework_id)
    homework.students_done_count = students_done_count
    homework.save()

    logger.info(
        'update_students_done_count_log : with id {id}'.format(id=task_id),
        exc_info=False,
    )
```

sample of how both task calling:

```
send_message_to_users.delay(users = SomeUserList)
update_students_done_count.delay(homework_id=SomeHomeWorkId)
```

project/celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hamclassy.settings')

app = Celery('hamclassy')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

projetc/init.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

after any change to task i run workers by this command:

```
celery -A project worker -l info
```

when i calling `update_students_done_count.delay(homework_id=1)` in an endpoint the log shown me that `recived task` but how much i'm waiting the task not execute. any idea?thank you

Comment: could you place a logging statement at the very top of `update_students_done_count`? Is it shown in the logs if you call the method?

Comment: @RaideR hank you for reply. i do that and now in log exactly after `[2019-07-15 16:25:53,197: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: apps.tasks.tasks.update_students_done_count  ` shown me `[2019-07-15 16:25:53,198: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] 91
` in yellow color and `[2019-07-15 16:25:53,199: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] update_students_done_count_log : with id 91` in next line and `NoneType: None` in next line again.for information i changed `exc_info=True,` . what is problem?

Comment: So your task gets executed? So where's the problem right now? :-)

Comment: your right but not working correctly, how i can found where is error? why `NoneType: None`  appear? even i try just for print simple string in `update_students_done_count`  and comment all code but again error exist :)

Comment: @RaideR thank you i found the issue with your great help master. the problem was for `homework = get_object_or_404(HomeWork, homework_id=homework_id)` that must be `homework = get_object_or_404(HomeWork, id=homework_id)` :) .you saved my day